# Directional derivative: is it correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given the following function
$$f(x,y)=2x^3y^4$$
I gotta evaluate $D_{\vec{v}}f(1,-1)$, where $\vec{v}=(-3,4)$.

I know
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(6x^2y^4,8x^3y^3)$$
and so
$$\nabla f(1,-1)=(6,-8)$$
Also, the versor of $\vec{v}$ is
$$\vec{u}=\left(\frac{-3}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right)$$
Then
$$D_{\vec{v}}f(1,-1)=(6,-8)\cdot\left(\frac{-3}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right)=-10$$
I want to know if what I did is right because WolframAlpha says the final value is $2$.

Comment: WA is allowing the computation without the assumption that it is a unit vector.

Comment: Beyond that, something was entered wrong in WA (likely).  The answer should be negative for sure